# Spring Data MongoDB - Add to db if not exist for DbRef field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, document, spring-data-mongodb

I have a little question about spring-data-mongodb:

I have ProductDocument class:

```
@Document
public @Data class ProductDocument extends DocumentObject {
    private String name;
    private int category;
    private int unit;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    @DBRef
    private ProducerDocument producer;

    private int unitInStock;
    private int status;
    private String city;
}
```

And suppose that I new the class by setting a new ProducerDocument that is not persisted on db.

When I check the product document from db, it is persisted perfectly:

[image]

However, new producer object is not persisted to producer collection. I mean if you check the producer id from producer collection, it returns null.

How can I set spring mongodb that if the value is new, add to the referenced collection too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data MongoDB does not cascade operations to referenced objects. Thus there is no configuration option do achieve the desired behaviour. Please see the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references) for more information.